# How do I ban a wifi network in Network Manager?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

My wifi connection drops sometimes and, for some reason, Network Manager attempts to connect to my neighbor's network, which requires a password that I don't know. The network in question is not listed in the "Edit Connections..." dialog and I can find no reference to it in any configuration file, but still the password dialog pops up every time my main connection drops. Is there a way to blacklist a wireless network so that the Network Manager will never attempt to connect to it? Or, equivalently, how can I remove the configuration data that causes the Network Manager to attempt to connect to this particular network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm... not sure why NeworkManager behave this way. This should only happen if you have already added the wireless network in the list and `Connect automatically` is checked.... maybe is from a connection configured by another users and made available to all users.

You can try to manually add the wireless network and the uncheck `Connect automatically`.

Comment: The network wasn't in the Connections manager before. But clicking on the network, failing to connect, then going into the Connections manager and unchecking "Connect automatically" did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon you saw might also be due to the wireless roaming that wpa_supplicant (which runs in the background) does at opportune moments, e.g., when your neighbors network has the same name as yours.

One way to stay on your own access point is to lock the saved connection to your APs MAC address. The MAC address of the connected Access Point is visible in `iwconfig` or in `iw wlan0 link`

Enter the MAC (or BSSID, same thing) here:
[image]