# Block connections to open WiFi networks

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

My users are using Ubuntu on corporate laptops. They don't have sudo permissions. IT security policy deny connections to open WiFi networks. How to setup Network Manager to deny connections to that networks and permit connections only to encrypted wireless networks?

Users will connect to random wifi. I don't want to restrict connections only to known wifi networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a directory `/etc/network/if-up.d`. Scripts in this directory are runs when new connection are established. I write script that checks connection mode of wifi network and if it's Open or WEP connection is dropped.

```
#!/bin/bash

encryption=$(wpa_cli status | grep pairwise_cipher | cut -d "=" -f 2)
wifiname=$(wpa_cli status | grep -w ssid | cut -d "=" -f 2)
interface=$(wpa_cli status | grep interface | cut -d " " -f 3 | tr -d "'")

if [[ $encryption == WEP* ]]; then
    nmcli device disconnect $interface
fi
if [[ $encryption == NONE ]]; then
    nmcli device disconnect $interface
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the only one way to do it.

You can disable Network Manager and setup specific wireless networks in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

If you setup your interface there, NM will stop managing the interface automatically.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted but i see no issue with your answer. Perhaps a bit more details and steps will help

Answer (score 0):

1. Change permissions access to Network Manager
2. Delete all open wifi from configuration
3. Check connect automatically to your wifi configuration, and enforce the configuration by adding mac address of your ap.

[How do I ban a wifi network in Network Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11990/how-do-i-ban-a-wifi-network-in-network-manager)

Comment: I don't know what MAC addresses will be. I want to disable possibility to connect to open wifi.

Comment: Are your users allowed to choose the connection? Is it possible to use custom script to handle this situation?

Comment: There are possibility to run script after interface is connected. But I don't know how to check security mode of wifi connection.

Answer (score 0):

- I thought the best is to use pre-up script which have all variable you need:

  ```
  /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/
  ```

  Check for example: `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools`

  Sadly, NetworkManager/dispatcher has not implemented it. See:

  `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown`

  ```
  # pre-up/pre-down not implemented. See
  # https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=387832
  #        pre-up)
  #            export MODE="start"
  #            export PHASE="pre-up"
  #            run-parts /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
  #            ;;
  #        pre-down)
  #            export MODE="stop"
  #            export PHASE="pre-down"
  #            run-parts /etc/network/if-down.d
  #            ;;
  ```
- Anyway, I see you have used `/etc/network/if-up.d` . It does not have all information you want like encryption type, but it has some like interface name and WiFi SSID. You can minimize external calls.

  You can study any environment with a simple script as this:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  #myuser

  logfile=/home/myuser/Desktop/wireless-pre-up.log

  touch $logfile

  echo args: $@ >> $logfile
  env >> $logfile
  echo == >> $logfile
  ```

  Output (wireless-pre-up.log):

  ```
  args: wlan0 up
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_NTP_SERVERS=1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_TIME_OFFSET=1
  DHCP4_SUBNET_MASK=255.255.255.0
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_DOMAIN_SEARCH=1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_HOST_NAME=1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_MS_CLASSLESS_STATIC_ROUTES=1
  CONNECTION_UUID=35821fc8-d6ce-4fb2-bb5d-ac4a52aa931e
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_SUBNET_MASK=1
  DEVICE_IFACE=wlan0
  IP4_NAMESERVERS=192.168.1.1
  DHCP4_DHCP_SERVER_IDENTIFIER=192.168.1.1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_NETBIOS_NAME_SERVERS=1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_DOMAIN_NAME=1
  DHCP4_DHCP_LEASE_TIME=86400
  DHCP4_EXPIRY=1441408529
  DHCP4_NETWORK_NUMBER=192.168.1.0
  IP4_NUM_ADDRESSES=1
  DHCP4_ROUTERS=192.168.1.1
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  IP4_NUM_ROUTES=0
  IP4_ADDRESS_0=192.168.1.4/24 192.168.1.1
  DEVICE_IP_IFACE=wlan0
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_ROUTERS=1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_STATIC_ROUTES=1
  DHCP4_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.255
  DHCP4_IP_ADDRESS=192.168.1.4
  DHCP4_NEXT_SERVER=0.0.0.0
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_INTERFACE_MTU=1
  DHCP4_DHCP_MESSAGE_TYPE=5
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=1
  DHCP4_DOMAIN_NAME_SERVERS=192.168.1.1
  CONNECTION_ID=MyWifiName
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_WPAD=1
  PWD=/
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_DOMAIN_NAME_SERVERS=1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_NETBIOS_SCOPE=1
  DHCP4_REQUESTED_RFC3442_CLASSLESS_STATIC_ROUTES=1
  ```