# Static IP forcing route to interface that is not connected to network

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, interface, wpa-supplicant

I am setting up a kiosk type system that some times connects to a specific ethernet source with a static IP and other times connects to a variety of wifi networks via wpa_supplicant. Once the system boots, it automatically starts a connection to a VPN. The problem is that if I specify the static IP in the interfaces file, then the system assumes that is the default route even if there is no ethenet connection and we are connected to wifi, and the VPN fails to connect.

Is there a way to make the system more dynamically choose what the default route will be?

This system is running 16.04. My interfaces file is below if that is useful.

```
$ more /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.1.1.200
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.1.1.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4


allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
pre-up wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

Answer (score 1):

- One way is by removing hard-coded gateway and writing an `if-up.d` script as in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/668493/26246) that check network then set default gateway using `route` command.
- Or Advanced way by setting up Dynamic Routing, [See Reference: Debian Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.dynamic-routing.html)